# Retrofit 2 request body without json, just a normal form?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

Every example and tutorial I've seen shows how to convert the request body to JSON, and it's not what I need.

It's not effective in my scenario since I'm not talking with node or w/e and I would be wasting computations. I would have to convert to JSON in my app and then decode from JSON in the back-end, that is expecting a regular form, there is no reason for me to do that.

I've tried every tutorial/example I could find.

```
public interface myClient {
    @GET("api/fetch-all")
    Call<List<ServiceGenerator.Data>> data();

    // How am I supposed to do this?
    @POST("api/login")
    Call<ServiceGenerator.Cookie> fetchCookie(@Body String email, String password); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use it like this

```
class User {
    String email;
    String password;

    public User(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

and then like you said

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/login")
Call<User> fetchCookie(@Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password);

User user = new User("a@a.com", "1234");
mService.fetchCookie(user.email, user.password)
```

This way you end up using FormURLEncoded method for post. Also Retrofit provides some ways to override it´s default converters for `ResponseBody` and `RequestBody`. As stated in the documentation:

> Retrofit Configuration
>
> Retrofit is the class through which your API interfaces are turned
>   into callable objects. By default, Retrofit will give you sane
>   defaults for your platform but it allows for customization.
>
> CONVERTERS
>
> By default, Retrofit can only deserialize HTTP bodies into OkHttp's
>   ResponseBody type and it can only accept its RequestBody type for
>   @Body.
>
> Converters can be added to support other types. Six sibling modules
>   adapt popular serialization libraries for your convenience.
>
> Gson: com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson Jackson:
>   com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson Moshi:
>   com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi Protobuf:
>   com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-protobuf Wire:
>   com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-wire Simple XML:
>   com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml Scalars (primitives, boxed,
>   and String): com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars Here's an
>   example of using the GsonConverterFactory class to generate an
>   implementation of the GitHubService interface which uses Gson for its
>   deserialization.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.github.com")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();

GitHubService service = retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);
```

> CUSTOM CONVERTERS
>
> If you need to communicate with an API that uses a content-format that
>   Retrofit does not support out of the box (e.g. YAML, txt, custom
>   format) or you wish to use a different library to implement an
>   existing format, you can easily create your own converter. Create a
>   class that extends the Converter.Factory class and pass in an instance
>   when building your adapter.

Hope it helps